# multiple form submission with one submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, html

I've been trying to think this through and figure out if it is possible or not. I'm using zen-cart as shopping cart software, but what I'd like to do, is hard code a page that is basically a list of 7-9 products, next to each product is a checkbox, so I'd like to figure out a way, via html,javascript or jquery to submit whichever forms(products) are checked to the cart. The typical form submission for a product looks something like this(sometimes there may be one or two additional hidden fields):

```
<form name="cart_quantity" action="index.php?action=add_product" method="post"      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="7">
    <input type="hidden" name="id[6]" value="9" id="attrib-6-9"> 
    <input type="image" src="buy_button.png" alt="Add to Cart" title="Instructional Video Part 1: Add to Cart">
</form>
```

There would be 7-9 of these on the page, each with a checkbox, so I'm assuming a script would need to figure out which ones where checked and submit them via the form action? Maybe there is a better way of going about this that I'm not thinking of because a)it's over my head or b)just haven't figured it out yet. Anyway is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, as this

```
$("#yourcommonbuton").click(function() {
    if($("#checkbox1").prop('checked') == true) $("#form1").submit();
    if($("#checkbox2").prop('checked') == true) $("#form2").submit();
    if($("#checkbox3").prop('checked') == true) $("#form3").submit();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: it looks like this would submit them all regardless of which ones are selected, is that correct?

Comment: @skylab, Can you tell me, how are the options received?

Comment: a simple solution that looks promising, so I just throw my checkbox and form selectors in and it seems like it should work.

Comment: How does this work? I read the Jquery doc but I don't get it. Normally submitting a form sends data to the server, resulting in an HTTP request and response. After the response, the page might be changed etc depending on your form's action. So wouldn't a multi-form submit be impossible -- the browser would only be able to do one, absent some sort of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have them all in the same form? is there any specific reason you have separate forms for each of them?

Put them all in the same form, and on the submit page(where the logic is) run a loop for all the checkboxes and for only those are checked, add them into the cart

The checkbox can have the value as the corresponding product id....

or something like
in html page it can have

```
Product1 <input typ='checkbox' name='checkbox[1]'>
Product2 <input typ='checkbox' name='checkbox[2]'>
Product3 <input typ='checkbox' name='checkbox[3]'>
```

in logic page

```
foreach($_POST[checkbox] as $k=>$v){
    if($v=='checked')
         //add to cart  like $_POST[product[$k]]  $_POST[amount[$k]] if there are such elements on the html page
}
```

Comment: no specific reason other than I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: Doing it this way, I assume that I would use  $_POST[cart_quantity[$k]] $_POST[product_id[$k]] etc. for the others?

Answer (score 0):

Add some sort of checkbox to each form, with a class:

```
<form name="cart_quantity" action="index.php?action=add_product" method="post"      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="checkbox" class="IsCheck" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cart_quantity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="7">
    <input type="hidden" name="id[6]" value="9" id="attrib-6-9"> 
    <input type="image" src="buy_button.png" alt="Add to Cart" title="Instructional Video Part 1: Add to Cart">
</form>
```

Add a button below all the forms, does'nt have to be inside a form at all:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit Selected" id="submit_btn" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#submit_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.IsCheck').is(':checked').each(function() { 
        $(this.form).submit(); 
    });
});
```